# Is it possible to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS without formatting?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, system-installation, lts

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS without formatting the target partiton??

HDD Partitions: I currently have Manjaro Gnome installed on `/dev/sda4` and the `/dev/sda3` is set to `swap`. The `/dev/sda2` partition is a `NTFS` partition with all my personal data. I have installed Manjaro in a single partition. My target parition is `/dev/sda1` which has my movies and videos. My partitoning scheme is `MBR`

Comment: Sorry, could you provide more information about your current system?

Comment: I saw it but didn't found it too much useful

Comment: OK.  You also have Windows in the system I guess (otherwise why would you have NTFS).  Other than the `swap` partition, what format are the other partitions? Also, where is `/home` the `NTFS`?

Comment: No windows. I used `NTFS` so avoid permission in the data partition and there is no `/home`

Answer (score 2):

It would depend what is the file system currently on your hard drive.  If you already had an older version of Ubuntu the answer is yes.  Note, however, if you have not properly partitioned your hard drive to have `/home` in its own partition, then you will likely loose all your information.

If you do not have such partition, it may not be too late. Depending on how much free space you currently have in your hard drive, you could create a new `EXT4` partition and copy all your files there.  Then, when you install Ubuntu you just make sure that you do not format that partition.

If you provide additional information we could edit the answer to be more specific.

Comment: I already have a `ext4` partition with a few movies and videos in it. I intend on installing ubuntu in that partition without formatting that partition. Is it possible?

Comment: Does this mean that you already have Ubuntu or other linux on your computer and you are upgrading?  As @Danibix and I said, we need more information to give more specifics.  Is your `/home` in its own partition?  If so, you can proceed without having your files deleted.  

Regardless what you do, you should still back up any critical files BEFORE you do anything to the partition(s).

Comment: Make sure you add the additional information to your original post so people trying to answer the question do not have to dig through every single answer and comment to find the information scattered all over the place.